# jmeter 5.4.1 selecting dynamic #id from custom attribute?

Tags: jmeter, css-selectors

I'm attempting to extract the hyperlink id `<a id="">` which changes upon request/refresh.

all values of the elements attributes change upon request including parents; with the exception of the cms generated "wicketpath" attribute which is static.

```html
<a class="hippo-tree-dropdown-icon-container container-selected" id="id639" wicketpath="root_tabs_panel-container_cards_2_panel_left_sections_list_3_section-view_extension.tree_tree_i_16_contextLink" href="javascript:;">svg</a>
```

i've attempted doing this by using the CSS selector extractor
[image: use of shared attributes between 20+ elements yielded 0 results]

and by targeting the custom attrubute
[image: using cms assigned attribute]

i'm trying to get the value of the `<a id="">`

Answer (score 0):

If you're stating that the `wicketpath` attribute is "static" I believe you should stick to it:

```
a[wicketpath=root_tabs_panel-container_cards_2_panel_left_sections_list_3_section-view_extension.tree_tree_i_16_contextLink]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)